# can I make tarte tatin without an oven?

Tags: oven, dessert, pastry

This is killing me! Buying an oven and getting it installed isn't really an option at this time.

What I'm thinking is cooking the apples in the caramel on the stovetop for longer, making a smaller version, in a mini cast iron pan. Cover the top and place something hot on top to even out the temperature.

Would I have issues with the puff pastry cooking through and going golden? Has anyone tried anything similar and would have suggestions? Any advice appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure you can obtain something interesting, but nothing can replace an oven for the puff pastry to cook correctly and uniformly. So even if you manage to get it cooked, the consistency won't be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not, or at least it's not going to be a tarte tatin.

you could do something like :
Cook the apples in the caramel, remove from the pan.

Place the dough in the (clean) pan and bake it (flipping it mid point) until it gets golden brown.

put the apples back on the dough and serve.

If you have a blow torch, you could give it a go just before service.